# Order E-mail is not sent automatically with credit card payments

Tags: orders, email, payment-methods

My website has two different payment methods: bank transfer and credit card. Automatic order email works fine when bank transfer is selected, but it does not work with credit card (you must go back to admin and send the order email manually to the customer). When I  open Order view (in Sales), the message "the order confirmation email is not sent" appears.

Order status is complete on the admin.

To enable credit card payments on Magento I have installed my bank "official" extension, and the full card payment process is working ok at this time.

So any help is welcome to get automatic order emails sent correctly to the customer. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask your extension provider for some support.

Comment: Well, I wish that was the solution, but they told me today they could not help much with Magento integrations...

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say that there is a setting within your credit card gateway which allows you to mark orders to a specific status on success. Try changing this to the same as the bank gateway. If this doesn't work you may need to make modifications to the banking gateway.

Comment: What is the order status after placing a cc transaction?

Comment: It would help if you post which payment method extension you are using exactly. Also is the code publicly available? It sounds likely that the extension is missing the code to send the email $order->sendNewOrderEmail();

Comment: @Fooman credit card payment extension is Redsys gateway (from Spanish bankers association), you can find it here: http://www.redsys.es/wps/wcm/connect/redsys/52db13b8-af9e-4d1c-b796-3890b72ddb75/redsys_magento.zip?MOD=AJPERES